# Getting started with Android

Tags: android

So, I'll be getting my T-Mobile G1 within a month or so, and I'm excited to start developing for it.

Has anyone started using it yet? Is there a dev wiki or anything set up for it yet?

Comment: **You can Use This tutorial** http://startandroiddevelopment.blogspot.in/

Comment: check developer.google.com   it will help you installing . how to programing and . . .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

- Google's android groups

This is probably the best place to go. However, a good search on google will most likely take you to one of these discussion anyways. Here, you can discuss about your difficulties possibly with the core developers too.

- Anddev.org

They're probably the most active groups so far (as of Sun, April 20, 2008) online regarding the development and the interactive community around android. Apart from the official google groups and the irc channel at #android on irc.freenode.net, they're probably the best place to go or ask questions.

- http://davanum.wordpress.com/

Development halted here but still some rather interesting things that have been done.

- phandroid.com

Didn't see much development things

- Androforge.net

A nice little repository, not a lot of files though.

I pulled it from my development wiki which hasn't been updated for a while but best of luck working with Android ... and T-Mobile G1

Answer (score 11):

No need to wait, the [Android SDK](http://code.google.com/android/documentation.html) has an emulator which works pretty well and looks suspiciously like the HTC Dream. Besides you wouldn't want to put code directly on your phone without testing it in an emulator of some sort anyway.

Answer (score 10):

After you have had a look at the [docs](http://code.google.com/android/documentation.html), another good place to see some example code with a little more meat on is [apps for android](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/) where the google devs publishes little sample apps every now and again.

[Anddev](http://www.anddev.org/) is also good for sample code, but watch out - the SDK has been changed a lot recently so some of the older stuff are out of date.

Answer (score 5):

Some tutorials in this website http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 4):

http://code.google.com/android/devel/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Google has set up a google code for it and has let a limited number of devs start playing arround with it.

Answer (score 3):

Also visit this for help:

http://andmob.wikidot.com/

Some us developers got together to assist everyone